# Magento: Customer Image Upload, Print Company

Tags: php, magento, file-upload

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to add an attribute or option for the customer to upload a couple of images along with their order, similar to other online printing companies.

In addition to the selected options for the order, a customer can upload a "front" and "back" image file to be printed by the company.

Has anyone found any documentation or examples for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it on the product page. That way the customer can add multiple products to the cart all with different images. So if it was a birthday card you could add 2 images for one, then add another card for someone else.

You need to create a custom field for the products.
There are two ways. The easy but long way is to go to Customer Options (when adding a product), then selecting "Add new option" then for input type select file.

Do this twice and the customer can upload 2 images.

Or [click here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-attributes-custom-fields) so you don't have to do this each time (it's too long for me to type it all here).

Hope this helps

Comment: I went to the knowledge base documentation, but when adding a custom field, there is no "file" option... but there is "Media Image" ... has the option been changed?

Comment: Sorry, it is called Media Image if you do it that way. Select that then go to Manage Label/Options down the right and call it "Image 1". After doing that go to Catalog -> Attributes -> manage Attribute Sets. Select default and add the 2 unassiagned attributes you just created into a category. Then it will appear in the options will appear in the add product page

Comment: Very helpful, Peter. Thank you. I'm going to try and apply this and see how it acts.